# PHP Explode Array Issue

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I would like to start off by saying I am very new at PHP.  The following code was written by an acquaintance who is no longer able to assist and I am trying to further develop some additional things with it.  I am running into an issue that I cannot wrap my head around.

The explode array is used to break a series of commands up into parts that are used within mysql statements to manipulate a database.

The issue I am having is some commands seem to work and some don't. See below:

```
if(isset ($_POST['commandline'])){
//handle cammand
$command = $_POST['commandline'];
$parts = explode(",",$command);
//print_r($parts);
//we know the first part is a command

//UPDATE NATURE CODE BY EVENT NUMBER  WORKS
//PART 1 IS THE EVENT ID PART 2 IS THE NEW CALL TYPE
else if(preg_match("/UTE/",$parts[0])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE runs SET calltype='{$parts[2]}' WHERE id='{$parts[1]}'");}

//UPDATE LOCATION EVENT NUMBER  WORKS
//PART 1 IS THE EVENT ID PART 2 IS THE NEW LOCATION
else if(preg_match("/ULE/",$parts[0])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE runs SET location='{$parts[2]}' WHERE id='{$parts[1]}'");}

//UPDATE DESCRIPTION EVENT NUMBER  WILL NOT WORK
//PART 1 IS THE EVENT ID PART 2 IS THE NEW DESCRIPTION
else if(preg_match("/UDE/",$parts[0])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE runs SET discrip='{$parts[2]}' WHERE id='{$parts[1]}'");}



else { header("Location: main.php?message=fail"); 
die;} 
}
```

As you can see from my comments the UTE and ULE command works however the UDE command will not work. I have a feeling it has something to do with the "UTE" and "UDE" part as if I change "UDE" to a random letter like "Q" it will work.

Anyone know what is going on and how to get the "UDE" part to work?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the closing brace of the first `if`? Or is this not the complete code? As it is you would get an error about unexpected T_ELSE on line 9 of your excerpt.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 - No there was no exchange of money as this was written by them as a favor to me and said acquaintance allowed me to continue using the code

Comment: @ScallioXTX - This is not all of the code.  There are several other commands above and below these commands that are working. The closing brace is here  `code` else {
        header("Location: main.php?message=fail");
        die;}
    
   
  } `code`

Comment: an `else if` statement but no original `if` statement?

Comment: Is your field really called `discrip` or should that be `descrip`?

Comment: *"No there was no exchange of money"* That explains why your acquiantance is trying to program backdoors into your application. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: can you show us some example of `$commandline`?

Comment: duplicated code... Piggy code... It can be written in much more secure way on 6 lines... eh, and more, are you really sure that parts has got always at least 3 items?

Comment: @VedranŠego - Yes...that is a spelling mistake I have not taken the time to fix yet.

Comment: @Kolink - Thank you for your judge of character on someone you have never met.  At the time of his part in the development we were focusing on functionality and not security.  To all that pointed out there is a SQL Injection risk....Thank you.  Now I just need to figure out how to eliminate that risk.

Comment: @EL - `$commandline` is the POST a form on a different page that calls this file. If you asking to see an example of a command: "ULE,120136,IN THE PARK"

Comment: @tomis - In reference to your parts question.  The number of parts depend on the number of commas in the command.  So in "ULE,120136,IN THE PARK" there are 3 parts.  But in a different command for example: "T,Unit Number,Location,Description,Remarks" will have 5 parts in the array.

Comment: @NC1787 If you do things right the first time, then you won't risk forgetting to come back later and fix it.

Comment: @NC1787 I know principe of function explode, but still, you have to test if there are at least 3 parts when you are using it - as warning can be raisen (on some production servers, error is possible for security reasons).

Comment: @NC1787 As conversation between you and Kolink... Security is at least 50% of functionality... at least, these things is not only about security, but also about possibility to write any character without be afraid of anything get broken.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy - #2) Not sure what you mean by this #3)Can you provide an example of this so I can test it?  #4) I ran `UPDATE runs SET discrip = 'testing123' WHERE id=120206` and it worked just fine

Comment: I edited my answer as requested.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy - Thank you for your helpfulness. #3) No that does not show up.  I even tried to `print_r($parts);` for UDE and it only returns Array followed by nothing.  If i `print_r($parts);` for ULE or UTE I get the following: `ArrayArray ( [0] => ULE [1] => 120207 [2] => IN THE PARK )` and `ArrayArray ( [0] => UTE [1] => 120207 [2] => SUSP PER )`   My overall question is why will UTE and ULE work but UDE will not?  You say in #2 that UDE has no special meaning but on that accord neither do UTE and ULE but they work.  That is what I cannot wrap my head around.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Kolink and to tomis - I understand the value of doing things correctly the first time.  If I knew a lot about PHP and SQL I would do it myself but that is not the case.  Hence the reason I am here asking for help.  Would either of you care to provide some assistance on the issue the SQL security risks?

Comment: @NC1787: I udated again.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy - Thanks again for your continuing help.  I will go further into depth:  The above code is in a file calle command.php. Command.php is called by main.php by the following code. `<form action="command.php" method="post">
Command Line: <input class="black" type="text" size="100" autofocus="autofocus" name="commandline"/>
<input class="black" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>`  I am typing the commands in that input field to manipulate the data to have it display in tables.  It is a mini police dispatching program.  after the command only......

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy http://mydomain/command.php shows up in the url.  I cannot tell if there are any other characters.  Also, I do not see what you are talking about shortening the commandline part at. If i change the post part it will not work due to how this file get the data from the main.php file.

Answer (score 1):

1) SQL Injection danger

2) /UDE has no special meaning, so that '/UDE/' will behave the same as '/ULE/' or '/ABC/'.

3) If you add an echo into above the deffective query, does it get shown?

```
else if(preg_match("/UDE/",$parts[0])){
echo 'Do you see that line here?';
mysql_query("UPDATE runs SET discrip='{$parts[2]}' WHERE id='{$parts[1]}'");}
```

4) What happens if you execute that query manually?

The last two points ara a general procedure to tell php and mysql errors apart.

Edit:
If you print_r($parts) and it is an empty array, then $party[0] cannot match your regex. In that case you must track down, why the explode() fails. Shorten the part after ?commandline= to ?commandline=xxx,yyy ; Then change it to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the error.

### Liekly reason:

does the part after ?commandline= in your url contain any of the characters "? & #" ? That would immediately end the parameter.